# wifi cracking using a network adapter which doesn't support packet injection

Tags: password-cracking, injection, wpa2, aircrack-ng

I'm trying to crack my wifi (WPA-CCMP) password to test its strength and security, I'm using the commview for wifi and aircrack-ng software on windows 10. I've three laptops, Windows 10 (64bit) with dual boot ubuntu 18.04, only Windows 10(64bit), Windows 7(32bit), with Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4A Wireless, Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165, Realtek RTL8191SE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC network adapters respectively. after some googling, I found that unfortunately, the first two don't support packet injection (am I right?). I couldn't find anything on the third i.e Realtek one, does it support packet injection? is it possible to capture the 4-way handshake without packet injection?

I tried using Realtek RTL8191SE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC network adapter but after capturing around 5000 packets in the tcp-dump format in commview for wifi application and pass it to aircrack-ng, I get an error saying "Packets contained no EAPOL data; unable to process this AP"

i really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/227444/packets-contained-no-eapol-data-unable-to-process-this-ap

Comment: What cards can and can't do is not really a security question but a hardware question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EAPOL packets happen at the very beginning of the connection due to it's nature.

If it's your own network, you don't need to "attack it". Just disconnect a device from it and connect back again, you'll start seeing the EAPOL message appearing in the capture.

The packt injection in this scenario it's to send a dissociation message to the AP spoofing the client, so it start the connection again and send the EAPOL message. So again, you can skip this part and manually turn off (disconnect) your Wi-Fi and turn it back on again.

If you want to know technicalities about the antennae, then it's just as @schroeder said, that's not security but rather hardware.